# Hide the primary panel in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, assistant

It's easy to hide assistan editor in Xcode 4, but you can only hide the second panel. Is there a way to make the secondary editor into the primary one, and hide the second panel in one keystroke?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not hide the primary editor. However, you can add shortcuts to hide and show the assistant editor in Xcode's preferences.

[image]